# Conditionally Covergent Series

Tags: conditional-convergence

Looking to prove that the following series converges conditionally

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$$

Plugging in some terms I see that,

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n} = 2 - \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{^4\sqrt 4}{3}-...$$ so this series is alternating

Using the alternating series test,

let $a_n =\frac{(1+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$

$\lim a_n = \frac{(\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{n}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\frac{n}{n}} = 
\lim1^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1 \ne 0$. Therefore by the Alternating series test, this diverges. If this working is correct then how do I show its conditionally convergent?

Comment: The limit of the sequence with absolute value is zero, yet you still can **not** deduce the series converges conditionally. You could either show this positive sequence is monotonically descending to zero or else use Abel's Test or Dirichlet's test...or something else.

Comment: @DonAntonio how can I use Abel's or Dirichlets test?

Comment: @jh I added an answer to this.

Comment: @DonAntonio thankyou for this answer, I understand now how the Abel Test works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n\cdot\sqrt[n]{1+n}$$

Now, $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n\;$ converges, whereas $\;b_n:=\sqrt[n]{1+n}\;$ is monotone and bounded, thus by [Abel's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_test) we have convergence

**Added on request**: It is not absolutely convergent because

$$\frac{\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+n}}n}{\frac1n}=\sqrt[n]{1+n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

and thus our series converges iff the harmonic one does (this  is the limit comparison test), but the harmonic one does *not* converge...

Comment: okay thank you for your answer, we have shown that it is convergent, how do we show that it is conditionally convergent

Comment: do I need to take the absolute value of this series now?

Comment: @jh Yes, for absolute convergence checking you must take the absolute value of the general temr sequence. I added this to my answer...

Comment: @jh Oh, dear: not at all! Will you please take a peek at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test ?

Comment: okay I understand what you have done here, I just got a little confused because you didn't include the limit on the equation. so taking lim an/bn gave us a positive number therefore if bn diverges which it does then an must diverge

Comment: @jh Exactly...and I did take the limit: that $\;... \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1\;$ means *exactly* that the left side's **limit** is 1 when...etc.

Comment: okay I see what you mean, thank you very much for your help. Abel's test makes a complicated question much easier

Comment: and this converges to 1 because $(1+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is infinity raised to the power 0 which is 1?

Comment: @JH No, not really because of that. You can use the squeeze theorem with other well known limit: $$\sqrt[n]n\le\sqrt[n]{1+n}\le\sqrt[n]{2n}$$ and both extremes converge to $\;1\;$ so does our sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the squeeze theorem:

$$\frac{n^{1/n}}{n}\leq \frac{(1+n)^{1/n}}{n} \leq \frac{(2n)^{1/n}}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

By the AM-GM inequality,
$$(n+1)^{1/n}=\left(\frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{1/n}\leq 1+\frac{H_n}{n}\leq 1+\frac{\log n}{n}\tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)^{1/n}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\left[(n+1)^{1/n}-1\right]}{n} \tag{2} $$
and the original series is the sum between a well-known conditionally convergent series and an absolutely convergent series (by the $p$-test). Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ is not absolutely convergent, the original series is conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent.